# Nothing shows up on output screen

Tags: java, println

I'm trying to do a really simple code, but whenever I try to make it print the first statement to get an input information from the user, nothing shows up on the output screen.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int grade[] = new int[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < grade[i]; grade[i]++){
    System.out.println("Input the student's degree");
    grade[i] = sc.nextInt();
        if(grade[i] < 10 ){
            grade[i] += 0.5;
        }
        System.out.println(grade[i]);
    }       
}
```

I can't really see the problem here. If anyone is wondering, I am using Eclipse Neon 0.2 IDE. Thanks for reading

Comment: Replase `grade[i]` with `grade.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grade array is empty. It has 0 in all indices. grade[0]=0, grade[1]=0 and so on...
Therefore the loop never runs and nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

grade[] is empty, so the for-loop never runs. An int-array is initialized with 0's.

Comment: Crap, you're right( in facty many is), I should've added a '(...;i++)' instead of pointing a (...;grade[i]). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Value of `grade[i`] is zero as has not been set. Thus you are not entering the loop.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < grade[i]; grade[i]++){
 //                   ^^^^^^^^ here
```

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you understand:

```
    int grade[] = new int[3];
```

Add this line under the above code.

```
    System.out.print(grade[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int grade[] = new int[3];

for(int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++){
    System.out.println("Input the student's degree");
    grade[i] = sc.nextInt();
    if(grade[i] < 10 ){
        grade[i] += 0.5;
    }
    System.out.println(grade[i]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try with this before for loop

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int grade[] = new int[3];
        System.out.println("Input the student's degree");
        grade[0] = sc.nextInt();
        grade[1] = sc.nextInt();
        grade[2] = sc.nextInt();
```

Comment: That works too, thanks! But wouldn't that be a bit more hustle for someone that is reading or analyzing my code?

Comment: then you can use like this for dynamicaly setting array length                    int grade[]=new int[sc.nextint()];

Answer (score -1):

you must rewrite your code, this is a sample code similar to yours with some modifications.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // import scanner package
public class demo {
    public static void main(String args[]){

            // create  a scanner
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            // double data type array
            double grade[] = new double[3]; 

            for(int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Input the student's degree");

            // input double data type value
            grade[i] = sc.nextDouble();
                if(grade[i] < 10 ){
                    grade[i] += 0.5;
                }
                System.out.println(grade[i]);
            }       
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the sample, but do you mind explaining the problem with my code?

Answer (score -1):

here is your code with a little modifications.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // import scanner package
public class demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    // create a scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    //create a double data type array
    double grade[] = new double[3];

    // create a for loop with modified condition
    for(int i = 0; i <= grade[i]; grade[i]++){

    // prompt input message
    System.out.println("Input the student's degree");

    // assign a double data type value
    grade[i] = sc.nextDouble();

    // test if grade is less than 10
        if(grade[i] < 10 ){
            grade[i] += 0.5;
        }
        System.out.println(grade[i]);
    }       
}
}
```